# surprising double comparison

Tags: java, primitive

I have messed with code execution result.

code:

```
System.out.println(0.2==0.1+0.1);
System.out.println(0.3==0.1+0.1+0.1);
```

output:

```
true
false
```

I know that 0.2 and 0.3 cannot transform  to binary correct.

Why do I see different results?

**UPDATE:**

Can I predict result in similar issues without compiler?

Comment: I don't know javascript

Comment: Check out `0.6==0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1`. It's true.

Comment: herohuyongtao - please to explain us  why it is true?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Test on your compiler.

Comment: please read the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) that @nr4bt posted.  This is a *complex* topic that every programmer should be aware of.

Comment: herohuyongtao, I believe you. I want to be posible to predict result

Comment: Sure you can predict it. But it is easier to use a calculator, as you probably cannot do binary IEEE conformant arithmetic in your head.

Comment: Is it depends on 100500 digit after comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP gave this:

```
<?php

printf("%0.20f\n", 0.1+0.1);
printf("%0.20f\n", 0.1+0.1+0.1);

?>
0.20000000000000001110
0.30000000000000004441
```

and

```
<?php
  echo 0.2==0.1+0.1?"true\n":"false\n";
  echo 0.3==0.1+0.1+0.1?"true\n":"false\n";
?>
true
false
```

The reaseon for the first to be "true":

```
<?php
   printf("%0.20f\n", 0.1+0.1);
   printf("%0.20f\n", 0.1+0.1+0.1);
   echo "\n";
   printf("%0.20f\n", 0.2);
   printf("%0.20f\n", 0.3);
?>
```

Output

```
0.20000000000000001110
0.30000000000000004441

0.20000000000000001110
0.29999999999999998890
```

Comment: nr4bt explained why *System.out.println(0.3==0.1+0.1+0.1)* returns false. but I have not answer why *System.out.println(0.2==0.1+0.1)* return true

Comment: According your results -  it is very very strange

Comment: about your update: Can I predict  result without compiler?

Comment: No, It's in the nature of floating point values and regardless what language you have, results are unpredictable to some extent. Either you set up a comparison routine which will compare exponent and mantissa as integers and separately or you go with @marcin_j ' s solution

Comment: it is *Double* - not float

Answer (score 9):

```
System.out.println(0.1+0.1+0.1);
```

output

```
0.30000000000000004
```

There is a rounding error on floating point arithmetics. Some values are can not be represented in base 2, you can't rely on comparing float numbers. 0.1 in base-2 is like 1/3 in base-10.

You can see the link below

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: I was about to add a comment that this was probably it.

Comment: Why ok for `0.1+0.1`?

Comment: Each time you perform an additional calculation with floats, you get more and more error in the answer. When you added just 2 floats, the error wasn't large enough to be considered !=.

Comment: @Takendarkk I cannot buy it. Check out `0.4==0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1`, it' true.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Interesting. That was definitely _not_ what I was expecting. I'm looking into it.

Comment: Offtopic, put OP please don't accept all suggested edits... I hate roboreviewers!

Answer (score 2):

What you see is the fact that floating point values are not very accurate and you should not for example compare them using `==` operator. For comparisons you should use epsilon compares, ie. for two floating point values f1 and f2

```
if  (Math.abs(f1 - f2) < EPSILON ) {
   // they are equal
}
```

Where EPSILON is some very small floating point value

Comment: ... Where EPSILON is some very small floating point value _reflecting the necessary precision in the comparison but not less than this_

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on `==` to work well for `float` numbers, whose results are undependable because they cannot be represented accurately on computers. When you want to check two `float` numbers equal or not, use `fabs(a-b) < epsilon` instead.

P.S. The following test are under `C++`, which gives surprising results (just for fun to show how un-dependable it is):

```
cout << (0.1==0.1) << endl;                                // true
cout << (0.2==0.1+0.1) << endl;                            // true
cout << (0.3==0.1+0.1+0.1) << endl;                        // false
cout << (0.4==0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1) << endl;                    // true
cout << (0.5==0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1) << endl;                // true
cout << (0.6==0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1) << endl;            // true
cout << (0.7==0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1) << endl;        // true        
cout << (0.8==0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1) << endl;    // false
```